# How to activate Scheduled refresh in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I want to activated Scheduled refresh for my report but it is disable for me.
Is it because I am using free version or there is there any other reason?

Comment: There is a ton of information out there on setting up refresh. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data#what-can-be-refreshed) on what types of data can be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You need either a personal- or an enterprise gateway configured in power pi (app.powerbi.com). Go to Settings - Settings - Datasets or Settings - Manage Gateways.
Hope this helps.